# Extract day number from existing column

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime

Using PostgreSQL 9.1 table, I want to extract day number from timestamp column.

table:

### id|name|timesatmp

I created a day column then tried to extract the day number following:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 16
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html

using:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM TIMESTAMP 'timestamp')
FROM table;
```

but seems like 'timestamp' is not the right format. how can i extract the day number from existing column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes for identifiers in instead of single. `timestamp` is a reserved word. Don't use it.

```
SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM "timestamp")
```

Comment: i got this error: `Encountered "\"timestamp\"" at line 1`

Comment: @Oxi Updated and Fixed